# Simple JavaScript loop + jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can someone tell why this is doesn't work? It works with alert(), but not when I am trying to use .css. I definitely need to use javascript loop.

```js
$(".select-buttons a").on("click", function() {
    var counter = 0;
    var i = setInterval(function() {
        $(".name").css("background", "red");
        counter++;
        if (counter === 3) {
            clearInterval(i);
        }
    }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: Please include a [mcve], otherwise this question is [off-topic (#1)](/help/on-topic).

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? If you change the background to red, what would happen the second time? The background is already red.

Comment: which part doesn't work? setInterval? setting background, firing click? show some html as well. And clearInterval is not gonna reset the background.

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Why do you think you need to use a loop?

Answer (score 0):

So this code is properly functioning.  Every 1 second (1000 ms) the background color will be set to red.  The problem is that there is no code to ever set this to be another color!  This means that the element will start with whatever background color was set before, and once the button is clicked it will wait a second, change to red, wait a second, change to red, wait a second, change to red, and then stop (still on red as it has been this whole time).

It looks like you were expecting the `clearInterval()` call to reset the background color but in what it actually does is stop the interval from setting the color to red again and again.

Assuming you were trying to make the element flash red, you'd need to have something actually set the color back to the initial color.  You could try doing something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/nd11brp7/1/) or come up with a better solution!